# GWT Tree: selection Listener

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I'm trying to add a `SelectionListener<TreeItem>` on my `Tree` using the `addSelectionHadler()` method.

For my proof on `onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeIterm> event)` I put a simple `Windows.alert()` but it don't do anything: when I select a treeItem that color change but doesn't open the window.

I write the Handler but if you want more code tell me.

Thank you.

```
        class SelHand implements SelectionHandler<TreeItem> {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
            Window.alert(event.getSelectedItem().getText());
        }

    }

    SelHand selezionatore = new SelHand();
    tree.addSelectionHandler(selezionatore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the straightforward:

```
tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {

    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
        Window.alert(event.getSelectedItem().getText());
    }

});
```

Comment: Don't work. It is on a VerticalPanel maybe it is for that implementation

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere else.